# How to model users and administrators in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm quite new to mysql. I want to make a database in mysql for a school. This database should store teachers' information and give some of these teachers the possibilities to create groups.

So I created a database that contains a table `group` and a table `professeur`. Group has many-to-many relationship with teachers and vice-versa which derives another table `Group_professeur`. Here is a simple structure of the tables:

Professeur:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `professeur` (
  `id_professeur` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_professeur` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prenom_professeur` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_professeur`),
  UNIQUE KEY `LOGIN` (`login`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MDP` (`passwd`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=103 ;
```

Group

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupe` (
  `id_groupe` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_groupe` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_prof_responsable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_groupe`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nom_groupe` (`nom_groupe`),
  KEY `id_prof_responsable` (`id_prof_responsable`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
ALTER TABLE `groupe`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_professeur_to_groupe` FOREIGN KEY (`id_prof_responsable`) REFERENCES `professeur` (`id_professeur`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Groupe_has_teachers:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupe_professeur` (
  `id_groupe` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_professeur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_groupe` (`id_groupe`),
  KEY `id_professeur` (`id_professeur`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `groupe_professeur`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `groupe_professeur_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_professeur`) REFERENCES `professeur` (`id_professeur`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `groupe_professeur_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_groupe`) REFERENCES `groupe` (`id_groupe`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Teachers can modify only the group(s) they created(i.e they can insert and delete members from their groups). Also, not all teachers have the right to create and modify groups.

After creating the tables, I was wondering who will give them the appropriate rights to do all these stuffs. I thought about creating an administrator. The admin can give the rights to certain teachers to create and modify their own groups and can also revoke these privileges.

I created a table which will store an administrator but who will give the admin the necessary rights to do these. Which brings me back to square one. And this table might have some relationships with other tables in the database thereby deriving some unnecessary tables.

Anyway I thought about changing the professors table to something general like `staffs` and adding the admin to the table. And then adding these staffs to the database. That means creating a new staff corresponds to adding the staff's information to the table `staffs` and then adding this staff as a user to the database. From there I can use SQL functions like `GRANT` and `REVOKE` to each user.

I'm not sure if this method is very efficient because these means if the school has 1000 professors then it has 1000 users in it's database. 
Is there any efficient way to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Propgramming is an art there are too many ways you can design your schema. I don't there is a right or wring solution to your answer. Even what you have looks right for me.

Comment: @EmmanuelN:  Which solution? You mean creating a user in the database for each staff member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling application user access using the built-in MySQL notion of a user is unorthodox. For a basic application, I would recommend having another column in the group table for an owner_user_id that would refer to the professor table. Then in the application code, check for that id when the group is being altered.
Good luck!

Comment: I do have such column. It's `id_prof_responsable` (check the table `Group`). It references the `id_professor` in the professor's table row(i.e group). This means that the professor is the owner of the table. But how can I implement the fact that the professor can insert or delete members from his group only in php/mysql?

Comment: try something like this:
function addMemberToGroup(currentUser,memberToAdd,group){
 if(group->ownerId == currentUser->id)
 {
  //add member
 }
 else{
  //deal with unauthorized user
 }
}

Comment: Thanks. I think I get the scope of it. In other words, when the professor logs in, i'll have to query the database for the professor's id and compare it with a groupe's owner id. If they are equal, the professor can insert/delete members from that group. Right?

Comment: So I don't need something like an admin to give privileges to certain professors to rights to create a group? Because not all professors have the right to create one. Then how can I know a particular professor can create a group?

Comment: Ok, that's a different problem. You could create these tables :
role (role int references role_type(id),user_id references professors(id)),
role_type(id int,type varchar);
insert into role_type(1,'ADMIN');
insert into roel_type(2,'GROUP_CREATOR');

than seed them with the user admin and create a screen where the admin can insert rows into the role table for group creators

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the table role_type very well. Let me try. From your tables to check if a professor has the right to create a group, i'll have to check if his/her id exists in the table role(user_id) and check if the corresponding `role_type(id) = 2?` And for the admin if the `role_type(id) = 1?`

Comment: exactly right. You could skip the role_type table and just "know" that 1 is "admin" and 2 is "group_creator", but it is considered better practice to keep it in a table, these are called ref tables. read on ref-tables here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at [Role-based Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)

[Another explanation by Tony Marston](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Seems that this issue isn't as simple as I thought